# WinJS AutoSuggestBox preserve selected suggestion

Tags: javascript, winjs, autosuggest

I am using WinJS.UI.AutoSuggestBox.
Every time when I chose item from suggestionCollection, that item appears in input, but when I click somewhere else (input lose focus), that item disappear from input and my search text back in input.

The same like on example: http://winjs.azurewebsites.net/#searchbox.

How to make my selection text to preserve in AutoSuggestBox after loosing focus ?

I would also appreciate some good documentation with examples for WinJS, I am new comer, and I always have problem to find what I need quickly, without looking a dozen of posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point here is that what you want is not a designed experience for the AutoSuggestBox. It is designed in a such way that user could continue refine his/her input over time, that is why it is preserved when input control loses focus.

By the way, if you have really good reasons to hack it, here is how:

1.You need to save somewhere selected suggestion:

```
var lastQuery; 

function querySubmittedHandler(eventObject) {
    var queryText = eventObject.detail.queryText; 
    lastQuery = queryText;
    ...
}
```

2.You need to subscribe to the onblur event in the input control. It is tricky one as this control is created dynamically:

```
var box;
WinJS.UI.processAll().then(function(){
    box = document.getElementById("autoSuggestBox"); 
    // this is how to get internal input
    box.winControl.element.querySelector("input").onblur = onblurinput; 
    // alternative
    // document.querySelector("#autoSuggestBox input").onblur = onblurinput;
});
```

3.Inside onblurhandler manually update the text value of input:

```
function onblurinput() {
    box.winControl.queryText = lastQuery;  
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. I thought it would be easier. I always expect that AutoSuggestBox works as "google search suggestion", not like this.

Comment: Is it possible to put id with every string value in AutoSuggestBox. I see that its take array, but it would not work with object array. Maybe with some template ?
I know this is another question, but if answer is short, why not. Thanks !

Comment: SuggestionList on examples is always array of strings. I need to put array of object where I can chose which property I want to show. When I put object in my suggestion list I get error: "Object doesn't support property or method 'toLowerCase'". Is it possible at all ?

Comment: I think it would be better to ask it as a new question.

Comment: New question would be good solution. Any good documentation for AutoSuggestBox or WinS would be appreciated also.

Comment: MSDN is the only official documentation on WinJS https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/develop/winjs

Comment: That I was afraid of :). I always have a problem to find out what I need there.